# Is testing through secondary testing app white box testing?

Tags: unit-testing, white-box, greybox, white-box-testing

So this software has zero unit tests. Basically you can't test this software unless the whole system is built and running. (This is crap I know)

They way these "white box" tests work:

- while the whole system is running, we inject basically a sequence of commands from a secondary testing app into the system directly rather than going through the user front, and verify if the behavior is correct from the testing app
- this allows isolated test cases to be scripted through the testing app rather than programming the system manually, thus saving time
- the testing app does not know any code level details of the software

Is this white box testing?

Comment: No, white box testing means you can see the code and write tests for the code methods.  However, you can get very close to it by covering all boundaries.  Some call it Greybox, I just call is good "Blackbox" testing.  Blackbox means you cannot see the code.  Either way you have to kind of sort of have a clue to what the app is doing either way.

Comment: Does being able to trace through the code in a debugger when using this secondary app count as being able to see the code? Is that white box?

Comment: No, when you really see the code and write test specifically for that, it is white box testing, everything else in a way is just guessing.  You can make good guesses but there's no tests that are as effective as white box testing.